# Prove that $F(s,x_0)=0$, $F(t,x)=1$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=0$

Tags: probability, parabolic-pde

Using the Dynkin's formula, prove that $F(s,x_0)=0$, $F(t,x)=1$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=0$

where $F(s,t)=2\int_{x-x_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2t}}du-1$

Comment: This can be done by simple calculus, why do you need Dynkin's formula?

Comment: My idea is to use the Dynkin formula to then deduce the distribution of the maximum process of Brownian motions

Comment: Assume that the above holds, how to use this result to obtain the distribution of the maximum process of Brownian motions?

Comment: I do not know this. You may have a look of the [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Financial-Markets-Springer/dp/1852333766).